# Group by col A and set col C for all rows in each group based on values in col B in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to run over a single, active sheet in Excel, grouping together all rows where column A matches.  This includes individual rows that have a unique value for column A.
Once the subsets have been determined, column B must be evaluated by each group (or individually unique col A entry) to determine whether or not any of the group's values for column B contain `fail` or `remove`.

If column B contains either one of the two matching strings, set column C for each row in the group (or individual row) to `remove`.

I'm currently working with a data set like this dataset
[image: this dataset]

And my desired result would look like this
[image: look like this].

I attempted to use grouping to determine the subsets and perform the required changes, but I only ended up with a VBA script to visually group the subsets by column A.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Excel formula to achieve this would be (in C1, and copied down)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"pass"),"keep","remove")
```

Obviously, one way this could be put into VBA is by using something like

```
Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
      "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,""pass""),""keep"",""remove"")"
```